# R group_by and summarise functions no longer functioning

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I've been using the `group_by` and `summarise` functions for some time now to summarise my data per data group. I have a data frame with Site_Number, Seeding_depth and plant_Numbers. I used this code:

```
Marina_Survival2=group_by(Marina_Survival,Site_Number, Seeding_depth) %>% 
summarise(mean=mean(plant_Numbers),sd=sd(plants_Numbers))
```

The output that I got was a data frame with 4 columns, `Site_Number`, `Seeding_depth`, `mean` and `sd`, With a mean and standard deviation for each of the combinations.

However, for some reason when I run the exact same code today I get a data frame with only 2 columns, `mean` and `sd` and only one value for each. I've tried reloading the `tidyverse` and `dplyr` packages but this hasn't worked.

Additionally, the `select` function also no longer works. It gives the error that I have unused arguments in my select command, even though it had no problem with it yesterday.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here and how I could fix it? As it would be very frustrating to rewrite my entire code so it no longer uses the package.

Comment: Your code snippet looks fine. Hence I would suggest you try to make a reproducible example of your issue including a snippet of your data and other code you use. Otherwise it's impossible to even guess what's wrong or what could be the issue.

Comment: Replace `Marina_Survival2=` by `Marina_Survival2  %>% `

Comment: for that `select` thing you can specify the library as well `dplyr::select `.

Comment: It sounds like you have other packages loaded that are interfering.  For example, if you do ecological work, you may have `raster` loaded, which also has a `select` function.

Comment: dbplyr is an R package for working with data stored in a database. You have no mention of a database in your question. Perhaps you meant dplyr?

Comment: @Simon.S.A. yes I did mean dplyr, I'm a bit dyslectic at times.

Answer (score 1):

@AmadouKone, you were right. I was using the ggbiplot function which was masking some functions of dplyr like summarise. I placed tidyverse at the end of my package loading list which fixes the problem.

Specifying the package like @AlexB suggested should have worked as well, especially if I wanted to use the functions of both packages. But I only need the one so I like the other solution better to make the script more streamlined.

Thank you all for your suggestions and help!